# Serialized PHP Reflection

Tags: php, serialization, reflection

Please consider the following example code:

```
<?php

class a {
    function b() {}
}

$r=new ReflectionMethod(new a, "b");
var_dump($r->getParameters());
$s=serialize($r);
$r=unserialize($s);
var_dump($r->getParameters());

?>
```

That produces the following output:

```
array(0) { }
Fatal error: ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getParameters() [<a href='reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters'>reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters</a>]: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the reflection object in [...]test.php on line 13
```

The question stands, is there a way to correctly serialize/unserialize Reflection objects in PHP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30324

> Serialization doesn't work on virtual
> properties and this problem usually
> occurs with internal classes.

Maybe that is the case with this method. However, I'm not sure the documentation is not clear. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php

Comment: Yes, the bug description seems relevant. The official documentation states that calling the built-in constructor is vital for extending (and hence initializing) Reflection objects, and it doesn't seem to happen on unserialize()

Answer (score 0):

Use the JMS Serializer to serialize private and protected properties and also virtual properties using methods.