# Caching Reflection Object

Tags: php, memcached, apc

i'm trying to cache reflection objects. Look at the code:

```
class A {

        public function __construct() {
        }

}

$memcache = new Memcache();

$memcache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$r = new ReflectionClass('A');

$memcache->set('a', $r);

$r = $memcache->get('a');

$a = $r->newInstanceArgs(array()); //here occurred the error
```

When I run the script it produces:

```
PHP Fatal error:  ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs(): 
Internal error: Failed to retrieve the reflection object
```

I've tried also using APC and also serializing and unserializing, but nothing changed.

Comment: What is `$r` before you save it to memcache? (`$memcache->set('a', $r);`) Also line numbers are missing with your error messages (to which line does which message relate to in your code example?). Also you said your tried something but do not provide any code, so we can only say: You did it wrong. Whatever you tried to do. Keep in mind that those reading the question need to understand it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialized PHP Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168731/serialized-php-reflection)

Comment: @Evert, you're right: 

$r = new ReflectionClass('A');

$r = unserialize(serialize($r));

$a = $r->newInstanceArgs(array()); produces the same error

Answer (score 2):

Reflection objects rely on instance references and virtual properties; which, are internal to PHP and can't be serialized.

```
// Stores only serialized reference to ReflectionClass
$memcache->set('a', $r);
//=> O:15:"ReflectionClass":1:{s:4:"name";s:1:"A";}

// Retrieves only a class instance & 1 attribute
$r = $memcache->get('a');
//=> ReflectionClass { public $name = "A"; }
```

To rebuild the ReflectionClass from unserialized class, reinitialize the class with the given name;

```
$r = $memcache->get('a');
$r = new ReflectionClass($r->name);
$a = $r->newInstanceArgs(array());
```